# How to get last & second last folder name from path using php?

Tags: php, path, substr

**Path:**

```
Home/Gallery/Images/Mountains
```

Last folder name in this path is **Mountains** and second last folder name is **Images**.

**I want to show this output:**

```
Last folder: Mountains
Second last folder: Images
```

Is it possible with **substr** or any another way. Anyone here who can give me answer? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple option using [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) and [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname):

```
$path = 'Home/Gallery/Images/Mountains';
$lastFolder = basename($path);
$secondToLastFolder = basename(dirname($path));
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cgOmM)**

Answer (score 1):

Just 2 small steps:

1. Split by "/"
2. Take last 2 items of the array

```php
$path = "Home/Gallery/Images/Mountains";
$parts = explode("/", $path);
$folders = array_slice($parts, -2);
```

Then, you will have the two folders available in `$folders` array

I strongly recommend to read more about array_slice here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: This error is showing: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Xampp\htdocs\project\index.php on line 58
Array

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string on '/' and use array_pop to pop each item out of the resulting array:

```
$str = "Home/Gallery/Images/Mountains";
$bits = explode("/", $str);
// Gives: 
Array
(
  [0] => Home
  [1] => Gallery
  [2] => Images
  [3] => Mountains
)

$last = array_pop($bits);
echo 'last: ' .$last; // Mountains

$next = array_pop($bits);
echo 'next: ' .$next; // Images
```